# stack vs Stacks tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation

I suggest that there should be a distinct [stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stacks) tag to represent the [Stacks blockchain](https://www.stacks.co/learn/introduction).

At the moment, if you attempt to put in a tag call [stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stacks) it automatically shortens to [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack).

How would one change this?

Comment: [tag:stacks] is too ambiguous (heck, even SE's own CSS framework is called Stacks). Create a [tag:stacks-blockchain] tag, and the issue will go away (don't forget to add a proper tag excerpt and wiki).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine didn't know that! good plan...

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stacks-blockchain/info

Comment: nice, thanks for making the tag!

Comment: There is also Stack Overflow's [design system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_system): *[Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/)* (though probably only relevant on meta sites). E.g., it was referenced in [a blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/).

Comment: eh, that one probably takes precedence, due to it's excessive use of !important

Answer (score 5):

As per [@OlegValteriswithUkraine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter-is-with-ukraine)'s [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418633/stack-vs-stacks-tag/418635#comment914526_418633), I added [stacks-blockchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stacks-blockchain) to avoid ambiguity of [stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stacks).

Comment: "*... to avoid ambiguity of `stacks`.*" is not "very clear" (to me at least)... A maybe better Formulation: "*... to avoid ambiguity with `stacks` which is already a [Synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stack/synonyms) for `stack`.*" (It wouldn't have been possible to create a `stacks` Tag anyway, as it already exists...!)